# Extended Audio File Services: ExtAudioFileRead

Tags: iphone

How to use `Extended Audio File Services: ExtAudioFileRead` to Performs a synchronous, sequential read operation on an audio file.

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"theme" 
                                                     ofType:@"mp3"];

NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
               initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];

[fileURL release];
```

How i can Performs a synchronous, sequential read operation on theme audio file. Currently have `AVFoundation.Framework` and should i add `CoreAudio.Framework` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use Extended Audio File services, you'll need to link to `AudioToolbox.framework`

Opening and reading a file using this API is fairly involved. There's some good information [here](http://cocoadev.com/index.pl?ExtAudioFile), and the [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/Reference/reference.html).

For my part, I've found the headers in `AudioToolbox.framework` to have the best documentation. See `ExtAudioFile.h`